# Java Hangman Code

Tags: java, arraylist

I have been stuck with this code for a while now, and would really appreciate some help. So basically my hangman code runs fine, but the display in the console, where the dashes are supposed to reflect which letters have been guessed correctly, and which letters remain to be guessed is completely wrong. I will post my code here. Since it was quite long, I will only post the relevant method. I feel as though the problem is with the display Array List, which I am being unable to update continuously.

```
     public void play() {

     String SecretWord = getWord();
     ArrayList <String> lettersInWord = new ArrayList <String>();
     for (int i=0;i<SecretWord.length();i++){
            lettersInWord.add(Character.toString(SecretWord.charAt(i)));
            }
     int remainingChances = getNumberGuesses();
     int noOfLetters = SecretWord.length(); 
     ArrayList<String> lowerCaseAlphabets = getAlphabetArrayList();
     ArrayList<String> display = new ArrayList<String>();
     for (int i = 0; i<noOfLetters; i++) {
         display.add("_");
     }
     System.out.println(printDisplay(display));
     Set <String> lettersGuessed = new HashSet<String>();
     while (remainingChances > 0){
         String question = readString("What letter do you want to guess?");
         if (lowerCaseAlphabets.contains(question)){
         System.out.println("Number of misses remaining equals "+remainingChances+"");
         int index = lettersInWord.indexOf(question);
            if (index== -1){
                lettersGuessed.add(question);
                remainingChances-= 1;
                if (remainingChances==0){
                    System.out.println("No "+question+". You lose! The secret word was "+SecretWord+"");
                }
                else if (remainingChances>0){
                    System.out.println("There is no "+question+" in the word");
                    System.out.println(printDisplay(display));
                    System.out.println("Guesses so Far :"+lettersGuessed+"");

                }
            }
            else if (index!=-1){
                while (index!= -1){
                    display.set(index, question);
                    System.out.println(printDisplay(display));
                    System.out.println("Guesses so Far :"+lettersGuessed+"");
                    lettersInWord.remove(index);
                    if (lettersInWord.size()==0){
                        System.out.println("You have won! Congratulations!");
                        return;
                    }
                    else if (lettersInWord.size()!=0){
                        index = lettersInWord.indexOf(question);

                    }
                }

            }
         }
         else {
             System.out.println("The letter you have chosen in invalid. You must pick a lower case letter from the alphabet!");

         }
     }
}            

    public String printDisplay(ArrayList<String> display){
    String View = "";
    for (int i =0;i<display.size();i++){
        View+= display.get(i) + " ";
    }
    return View;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this line:

`lettersInWord.remove(index);`
When you call this you are shifting the arraylist, so that when you get the new index it will be incorrect, as it has been shifted. For instance, let's say the secret word is "test". At first the arraylist will be [t,e,s,t], and when you ask for the index of the first t, you will get 0 (correct). But after calling arraylist.remove you'll have [e.s.t]. When ask for the index of the second t, it will return 2 instead of the 3 you are looking for.

Perhaps you should have a second arraylist which keeps the secret word intact which you will use for index lookups, and keep the first one to store the remaining letters.

Comment: I still seem to be getting the same problem though.

Comment: Do not remove anything from `lettersInWord`. Just replace the characters in the founded index with `null`. That'll keep your indices right while preventing `indexOf` to find any already founded characters.

Comment: So if I used lettersInWord.set(index,null), would the null elements be counted when I use the lettersInWord.size() call?

Comment: So it solved the display problem, but the game never reaches the "you have won" anymore since lettersInWord.size() never becomes equal to zero. So I am guessing the null elements are counted towards the total then. Any idea as to how this may be fixed?

Comment: Maintain a separate counter which you decrement each time you replace a character with null. When it counts down to 0 the user has won.